# vhdl multidimensional array

Tags: arrays, vhdl

I am working with a multidimensional array in vhdl and I  have the following vhdl code:

```
type mem_array is array(0 to 7) of STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (31 downto 0);
```

I am a total beginner to vhdl and my question is about the size of the array I am declaring, by instantiating this array does it mean I have 256 (8 bits large 0 to 7) positions of 32 bits each, or do I only have 8 positions of 32 bits each?

Comment: That's not a multidimensional array, mem_array has only one index. It's a single dimensional array type with an element that is of an array type. *An array object is a composite object consisting of elements that have the same subtype.*

Comment: What you have is an array containing 8 elements. Each element is itself an array of 32 `std_logic` elements.

Comment: You should just try to write some code and run a simulation. That way you can see what is happening.

Answer (score 0):

You declare, that you want make new type which will be array of 8 elements of type `std_logic_vector(31 downto 0)`, so you have 8 positions of 32 each.